# paypal amount 0 on order summery page

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

Amount $0 on order summery page.

My Code for Buy Now Button is

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AF">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.10">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="License Option">License Option</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
                <option value="Single User">Single User </option>
                <option value="Site License">Site License </option>
                <option value="Global License">Global License </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In order summery page it shows amount $0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create button in your PayPal account, please do not change the name and value fields generated there. All data are saved in PayPal system and could not be modified in code line. If you are trying to create a customized button, please refer to below page for its details.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/#id08A2G0920QN

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have modified the button, which is what's probably causing the issue.  When using a hosted button, typically the amount doesn't appear in the code.  This is one of the reasons behind the hosted button, it keeps a person from viewing the code and modifying the amount.  If you added the line of code in there for the amount, after creating your button this is probably the issue.  Either you need to set the amount when creating the button in your account if you are wanting to use a hosted button.  Otherwise if you want to be able to edit the amount in the code, you need to create a non hosted, clear text button.  This can be done by setting your button not to be hosted on step 2 of the button creation process.  Then once the code is generated, it will be encrypted.  You have to then select clear text/un-encrypted to generate the HTML code that you can edit.